# Can i disable the theme in Wordpress for one page?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, themes, web-deployment

i have Wordpress theme which is on every Page.
Now i want to disable the theme for one page so
i can use this blank site for someexperiments.

- At the moment every page has the design
- Even the blank site has the theme on it

Is that possible and if so how? :)

Comment: The theme is how the website gets displayed, so you can't disable a theme or nothing would be displayed :) Do you mean you want to be able to switch themes like the answer below, or do you want to have an unstyled appearance for a specific page/set of pages?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yeah, this would be also cool. Then i can change the theme on the specific page to a blank theme and im good to go.

Comment: @FluffyKitten My goal is to make an iFrame from this page and therefore i need a blank Page. But everytime i create a new page, the selceted theme comes with it. When i deselect the theme it is gone everywhere

Comment: OK, there are a few ways we might be able to do this, depending on what you need on the page without your iframe and how familiar you are with WP theme development.Firstly, what *exactly* do you need on the page, e.g. logo, nav menu and footer, just a heading; a link back to the main website; just a title or absolutely nothing - just the bare bones of a page with just the `html`, `head` & `body` tags, for example.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Your idea to look at the whole thing from this perspective has brought me to the result. I needed a completely blank page. I was able to solve the whole thing through this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFv2JV9aRHs) Thank you very much!

Comment: That’s where I was heading, except I was going to give you code to create your own page template instead of using another theme/plugin -I’ve done this myself before to create landing pages for email campaigns - but glad you found what you needed!

Comment: i don't think "the theme is how the website gets displayed" has anything to do with "disable a theme"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/

I've used this plugin in the past. You can use it to have a different theme on every page. Is this what you mean? You could use a simple theme like Twenty Sixteen which was pretty clean.